Trying to pre-register ports to run Owin without Admin doesn't work
Currently working on a PoC of sorts to find out if I can run Owin self-host without admin rights if I do port/url/firewall stuff with admin rights before execution of the app.
For this purpose I have written this register method:
public int FindAndReserveUrl(int startPort, int endPort)
{
    for (int port = startPort; port <= endPort; port++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Checking port {port} availability...");
        if (IsPortAvailable(port))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Port {port} is available. Checking URL reservation...");
            string url = $"http://+:{port}/";
            var (output, error, exitCode) = ExecuteCommand("netsh", $"http show urlacl url={url}");

            // Considering a reservation non-existent if the output only contains the generic header
            // and no specific reservation details.
            bool noReservationExists = output.EndsWith("\n-----------------", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

            if (noReservationExists || exitCode != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"No existing URL reservation found for {url}. Proceeding to reserve.");
                AddUrlReservation(port, "Everyone");
                return port; // Successfully reserved this port.
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Existing URL reservation detected for {url}, moving to next port...");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Port {port} is in use, moving to next port...");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Failed to reserve a URL within the specified port range.");
    return -1; // Indicate failure to find and reserve
}

public void AddUrlReservation(int port, string user)
{
    string url = $"http://+:{port}/";
    // Prepare the command to add the URL reservation
    string addCommand = $"http add urlacl url={url} user={user}";

    // Execute the command and capture the output, error, and exit code
    var (output, error, exitCode) = ExecuteCommand("netsh", addCommand);

    // Provide feedback based on the command's execution result
    if (exitCode == 0)
    {
        // Success: Log the successful addition with any output provided
        Console.WriteLine($"Successfully added URL reservation for {url}.");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(output))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Details: {output}");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Failure: Log the failure, including both the output and error information
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to add URL reservation for {url}.");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(output))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Output: {output}");
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error}");
        }
    }
}

This executes a port registration via "netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:6003/ user=EVERYONE" (also tried with my personal user).
But still, whenever I try to run the app after registration I get the following error:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener.Start(HttpListener listener, Func`2 appFunc, IList`1 addresses, IDictionary`2 capabilities, Func`2 loggerFactory)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinServerFactory.Create(Func`2 app, IDictionary`2 properties)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(IAppBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at OwinNoAdminPoC.Program.Main(String[] args)

When I double check the registrations they're there and the port being used in the owin self-host is correct too (6003 for everyone, 6004 for my user, tried both).
Reserved URL            : http://+:6003/
        User: \Everyone
            Listen: Yes
            Delegate: No
            SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

    Reserved URL            : http://+:6004/
        User: [redacted]
            Listen: Yes
            Delegate: No
            SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;[redacted])

Any clue what else I'm missing or what else I need to do so I can run my application without admin rights?

This implies that you need to preregister the exact route(s) used. Looking at the owin source here should give you ideas what to preregister for your app. If you use the source code for owin you might want to debug the startup of your app to see the generated and registered urls in the linked piece of owin code.

The linked Stackoverflow article talks about HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup that the method HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes, taken from your stacktrace, uses also.
